# how to set custom value in updatedAt field in sails

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I want to save updatedAt by 2 way.

1) If I'm passing some value in that object while saving data then it should save by that date else current date and time.

i.e Today current date is `2018-07-27 16:41:14` and if I set  updatedAt = '2018-03-13 17:40:44' then it should be set as '2018-03-13 17:40:44'

2) It should save like autoUpdatedAt = True. So, if updatedAt is not set then it should take current date and time.

i.e Today current date is `2018-07-27 16:41:14` and if updatedAt is not set then it should be set as `2018-07-27 16:41:14`

---

Thanks everyone for your effort. However, I found the solution as below.

Make below changes to specific model class.

```
  autoUpdatedAt: false,

updatedAt:{
      type: 'datetime',
      defaultsTo: function(){return new Date();},
    }
```

//LifeCycle callback

```
beforeUpdate: function (valueToBe, proceed) {
    if (valueToBe.updatedAt == null) {
      valueToBe.updatedAt = new Date();
    }
    return proceed();
  },
```

Comment: In another word, how to not update updatedAt column value for a specific model at the time of migration only? Just fyi, migration script is written in python

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a date-picker component and make it a required field that can easily default to the current date.

Comment: This won't work. I'm using sails and for specific scenarios, I do not want to updatedAt with current date and time.

Comment: @Raqem I'm not sure we need a datepicker here since this is about timestamps

But Jwalin, I'd recommend making a backend action that does what you need.  Send the timestamp as a JS timestamp (number of epoch milliseconds), and ideally, save it in the database the same way.  This is the conventional approach in Sails v1.

Comment: @mikermcneil, Kindly check my answer. I just updated in the description of the question asked and let me know your views.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @mikermcneil, I would also suggest saving it as a JS timestamp. You can use momentJS to format it later when you need to. I would also handle the logic in the controller and not in the model. So for example, in the controller you could make a dataToUpdate object that may or may not contain the updatedAt data, then when you make your call to the DB it would look like:

```
Record.updateOne({id}).set({
    someField: dataToUpdate.someField,
    someOtherField: dataToUpdate.someOtherField,
    updatedAt: dataToUpdate.updatedAt ? dataToUpdate.updatedAt : Date.now(),
    ...
})
```